# Can I get a single entry visa + transit visa when I visit Canada

Tags: usa, transit, canada

I'm traveling from India to Canada to attend a conference in Montreal, Canada, this is an educational conference.

So here is the itinerary that I have in mind, since I want to visit a relative living in San Fransisco, USA.

India -> Montreal -> SFO -> Montreal -> India

Below is my question:

- Say I can only get a single entry visa into Canada, can I still travel to USA ( I also have a valid USA tourist visa ) and then apply for a transit visa to Canada to go back to India?

I know that if I get a multi-entry visa I'm all good.

Let me know please, 
-Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If you are granted a single-entry visa, you can apply for a transit visa.  But it seems you would not need to, as there is apparently an exception that applies to the [United States](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16):

> ## Single entry visa
>
> A single entry visa lets you travel to Canada only one time. For instance, you may only be eligible for a single entry visa if:
>
> - you are eligible for a fee-exemption and the purpose of your entry to Canada is limited (such as, for an official visit by a foreign national)
> - you are taking part in a one-time special event in Canada
> - there are approved country-specific procedures or guidelines in place.
>
> In most cases, once you have left Canada, you will need a new visa to enter Canada again.
>
> You won’t need a new visitor visa to return to Canada if you are travelling directly to the United States (including its Territories and Possessions) or St. Pierre and Miquelon.

Comment: But the educational conference is in Canada. I'm only traveling to USA to meet my brother.

Comment: @abhididdigi why would that matter?

Comment: Because the exception mentions this "if you are travelling directly to the United States (including its Territories and Possessions) or St. Pierre and Miquelon.". I'm not traveling directly to USA, I'm attending a conference in Canada AND then traveling to USA.

Comment: @abhididdigi oh, I see.  As far as I can tell, it means traveling directly to the US *from Canada,* because the context is the conditions for reuse of a single-entry visitor visa "to enter Canada again."

Comment: It sounded a little weird, so I went and looked it up in the actual regulations. In [SOR/2002-227 p 190(3)(f)](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2002-227/page-41.html#s-190ss-(3)p-(f)ID0EDCEA) it does indeed state you can return from a visit directly to the USA. Canada's immigration web site tends to be confusing, so it's best to be sure. The proposed itinerary is indeed OK on a single entry temporary resident visa.